# javascript menu, How to close when mouse outside of div?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

this is my first pure JavaScript script as you can probably tell, by the length of it! I'm at a loss to workout how i can get the child links which are in a div with a class called 'menu' to close when i leave that div. 
I've tried to write an If argument to set it to close when i leave the 'A' and also a 'DIV' and that doesn't seem to work?
Any help would be much appreciated and sorry for the overly long code! 
Please no Jquery for now, thanks!

```
<script>
    // Variables
    var getFirstMenu = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    // Use selectors
    var getMenuClasses = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
    // Hide drop down menus
    for(var i=0; i < getFirstMenu.length; i++){
      getFirstMenu[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    // =============================
    // Show Menu on mouseover
    function showDropdown(e){
     var el = e.target;
    if(el.nodeName == 'A'){
        for(var i = 0; i < getMenuClasses.length; i++) {
          if(el == getMenuClasses[0]){
            getFirstMenu[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
          }else if(el == getMenuClasses[1]) {
             getFirstMenu[1].style.visibility = 'visible';
          }else if(el == getMenuClasses[2]){
            getFirstMenu[2].style.visibility = 'visible';
          }
        }
      }
    }
    var getMainMenu = document.getElementById('menu');
    getMainMenu.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
        showDropdown(e);
    },false);

    // =============================
    // Hide Menu on mouseout
    function mouseOutMenu(e){
     var el = e.target;
      if(el.nodeName == 'DIV')
        for(var i = 0; i < getFirstMenu.length; i++){
        getFirstMenu[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
          }
    }
    getMainMenu.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
      mouseOutMenu(e);
    }, false);
```

Comment: Any chance to make this into a snippet or fiddle, and to add the html of your menu, so that we could see the structure?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/joegoose/5c8sLqwc/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add a Handler to the document-object

```
document.addEventHandler('mouseover', function(){
   // close it
}, false);
```

Or when this is about to hide a submenu: Add the handler to the menu which then hides the menu on mouseover

Comment: shall i use this in place of my mouseOutMenu(e) function?

Comment: I actually don't know because your fiddle shows a menu where I couldn't even hover the submenu because it was disappearing in any case. My answer just should give you the  right direction

Answer (score 0):

Look [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5c8sLqwc/3/)
Code :

```
        // Variables
        var getFirstMenu = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        // Use selectors
        var getMenuClasses = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
        // Hide drop down menus
        for(var i=0; i < getFirstMenu.length; i++){
          getFirstMenu[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        // =============================
        // Show Menu on mouseover
        function showDropdown(e){
         var el = e.target;
        if(el.nodeName == 'A'){
            for(var i = 0; i < getMenuClasses.length; i++) {
              if(el == getMenuClasses[0]){
                getFirstMenu[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
              }else if(el == getMenuClasses[1]) {
                 getFirstMenu[1].style.visibility = 'visible';
              }else if(el == getMenuClasses[2]){
                getFirstMenu[2].style.visibility = 'visible';
              }
            }
          }
        }
        var getMainMenu = document.getElementById('menu');
        getMainMenu.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
            showDropdown(e);
        },false);

        // =============================
        // Hide Menu on mouseout
        function mouseOutMenu(e){
         var el = e.target;
          //if(el.nodeName == 'A')
            for(var i = 0; i < getFirstMenu.length; i++){
            getFirstMenu[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
              }
        }
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('div').length; i++){
      document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
          mouseOutMenu(e);
        }, false);
              }
```